# Start one of three activities based on the chosen checkboxes

Tags: java, android, android-activity, checkbox, android-listview

I created an application that have 4 activities: login, sport, technology and sporttechnology.
the login activity that contains  two check boxes in a listview (named sport and technology) and a button, when press the button the program check the text of the checked check boxes and opens the right activity based on it, if only the sport checkbox have been checked it should opens the sport activity, if only the technology checkbox have been chosen then it will open the technology activity, if both checkboxes have been checked then it will open an activity named "sporttecknology".
when run the app, when I choose only the sport checkbox and then press the button,  it opens the sport activity. but when I choose only the technology checkbox and then press the button the app stop working, and also that happens when I choose both checkboxes then press the button,

so is there any error in my code?

private void checkButtonClick() {

```
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
            //responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

            ArrayList<Interestclass> interestList = dataAdapter.interestList;

            for (int i = 0; i < interestList.size(); i++) {
                Interestclass interest = interestList.get(i);
                if (interest.isSelected()) {
                    responseText.append(interest.getName());//"\n" +
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String start = responseText.toString();

            if (start.equals("Sport")) {
                Intent intentSport = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sport.class);
                startActivity(intentSport);
            }
            else if (start.equals("Technology")) {
                Intent intentTechnology = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Technology.class);
                startActivity(intentTechnology);
            }
            else if (start.equals("SportTechnology")) {
                Intent intentSportTech = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SportTechnology.class);
                startActivity(intentSportTech);
            }
            else {
                Intent intentTechnology = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Technology.class);
                startActivity(intentTechnology);
            }
```

/*
                switch (start) {
                    case "Sport":
                        Intent intentSport = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sport.class);
                        startActivity(intentSport);
                        break;
                    case "Technology":
                        Intent intentTechnology = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Technology.class);
                        startActivity(intentTechnology);
                        break;
                }*/
            }

```
    });

}
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you provide your logcat?

Comment: Have you declared all classes in mainfest file?

Comment: it didn't gave me an error, but when I run it on the emulator it stopped working, I don't know what is the logcat because I am new in android, where I can get it to provide it . and yes, I declared them in the mainfest file.

Comment: The Logcat allows you to view the system's debug outputs. It should look something like this
http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/tut-images/android-logcat.png

If you read the red lines, they tell you where the exception was called (if it ever crashes), and the type of exception that was raised.

Very useful for debugging your apps

Comment: this is the first two lines from Logcat: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.newsapp.mynewsapp/com.newsapp.mynewsapp.Technology}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.newsapp.mynewsapp.Technology cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: Does the class Technology extends Activity? And is it defined as an activity in the manifest?

Comment: Thanx all, Technology class was empty, and that why it wasn't work. now it solved .